# I can't copyLineDown in vscode with linux mint

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I recently moved to linux mint,
and in vscode I have issues with alt key.

i want to copy line down but it doesn't get alt key, actually vscode pass alt key.

what should i do?

i tried to remap it but when i try to map the copyLineDown action to `shift + alt + down arrow`

it automatically change it to `shift + down arrow`

Comment: Welcome! What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste what you see here in a code block.